# Criptografar senhas

Tags: laravel, login, hash, bcrypt

Preciso gerar uma senha padrão para os usuários da minha tabela *login*. A senha deve ser a mesma para todos os usuários para o primeiro acesso ao sistema. O cadastro já existe, porém tenho que modificar as senhas. O problema acontece quando atualizo as senhas, apenas o primeiro usuário da tabela consegue fazer o *login*.

```
public function recadastroSenha(){

    $users = User::whereRaw("flag_del = 0 ")->get();

    foreach($users as $user){

        $senha = "senha123";
        $user->password = bcrypt($senha);            
    } 
    $user->save();
}
```

Mesmo atualizando todas as linhas da tabela com criptografias diferentes, apenas o primeiro user realiza o *login*.

Comment: Insira o `$user->save();` dentro do foreach também

Comment: @Miguel obrigada pela resposta, também já tentei desta forma e apenas funciona com o primeiro registro da tabela.

Comment: Lembre-se que está a selecionar todos cujo `flag = 0`, é isso n é? De qualquer maneira o `$user->save();` deve estar dentro do foreach, senão só vai inserir o dado para o ultimo `$user` que passou pelo `foreach`

Comment: Isso, os usuários com essa flag são os "não deletados" no meu bd, mesmo salvando dentro do foreach parece que o sistema só aceita uma senha diferente para cada user, mesmo com strings diferentes.

Comment: Estranho isso. E só consegue entrar depois com o primeiro $user?

Comment: sim, é isso que acontece.

Comment: Será que é só esse que tem `flag_del = 0`? experimente fazer `echo $user->password. '<br>';`, para ver quantas vezes ele imprime

Comment: todos estão como flag_del e acontece a alteração nas senhas, verifiquei agora que o primeiro e o ultimo cadastro conseguem acessar.

Answer (score 0):

Teria que ser o método `save` dentro do `for` para ***alterar a senha***:

```
public function recadastroSenha(){

    $users = User::whereRaw("flag_del = 0 ")->get();

    foreach($users as $user){

        $senha = "senha123";

        $user->password = bcrypt($senha);

        $user->save();

    } 

}
```

Comment: infelizmente o problema não é este.

Comment: Qual o problema relate por favor?